# Wiring up gulp to run mocha tests written in coffeescript

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mocha.js, gulp

Stitching together things off of websites I tried this

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var coffee = require('gulp-coffee');
var mocha = require('gulp-mocha');

gulp.task('test', function() {
    return gulp.src(['tests/*.coffee'], { read: false })
            .pipe(coffee({bare: true}).on('error', gutil.log))
            .pipe(mocha({
                reporter: 'spec',
                globals: {
                    should: require('should')
                }
            }));
});
```

This always gives me an error on the first line of my tests/test.coffee file

```
require 'should'
describe "something", ->
    it "fails", -> true.should.equal false
```

This error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { require 'should'
                                                                  ^^^^^^^^
```

In addition it doesn't seem right to do this in one task. Each one feels like it should be a task that depends on the output of the previous.

How do I make all these pieces come together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have almost identical gulp config as yours, what I  did to fix it was:

```
npm install --save-dev should
```

The `--save-dev` part is optional, but I like to store my dependancies into `package.json` file  for easier portability.

**Edit:**

I have noticed that you're first piping it to coffee. You don't need to use this if using `Gulpfile.coffee` (you guessed it, `Gulpfile` written in `CoffeeScript`), mocha will run it fine as `CoffeeScript` file.

This is my `test task` in `Gulpfile.coffee`:

```
gulp.task 'test', - >
    gulp.src(testSources,
        read: false
    )
    .pipe(mocha(
        reporter: 'spec'
        globals:
        should: require('should')
    ))
```

To get Gulp to parse `Gulpfile.coffee`, save this as **`Gulpfile.js`**

```
require('coffee-script/register');
require('./Gulpfile.coffee');
```

**Edit 2:**

I have noticed that the `JavaScript` version isn't working as expected.

My *only* suggestion is to use `Gulpfile` written in `CoffeeScript`, that way it works fine. I could share mine to speed it up for you, but it takes less than 5 minutes to convert it to `CoffeeScript` manually, or even faster using [Js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org/).

---

Or look at this [Gulpfile.js](https://github.com/Dashed/coffeescript-seed-project/blob/master/gulpfile.js) (not my work).

---

Or use [Chai](http://chaijs.com/) and use following code:

```
chai  = require 'chai'
chai.should() # add should to Object.prototype

describe "Test", ->
    it "should pass", ->
         true.should.equal true
```

Comment: So how do you launch gulpfile.coffee? the gulp command doesn't pick it up.

Comment: I have updated the answer to describe how to run `Gulpfile.coffee` if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it running now. Any idea why using mocha from a coffee file works but from js doesn't? It seems like it would be a simple function call either way

Comment: No problem at all :) I don't have much experience, I was setting up my gulp workflow when I found your question, so I'm starting with gulp, mocha and coffee as well. I'm guessing it's the way gulp works, it doesn't add `should` correctly. Using [cahi](http://chaijs.com/) would probably prevent this error, because it has it's own way to add should.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to run coffeescript specs is `npm install coffee-script`.
No need to have a gulpfile in coffeescript.

If you have coffeesctipt installed it's enough to have test task like this in your gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('test', function(){
  return gulp.src('./specs/**/*.spec.coffee')
    .pipe(mocha({reporter:'nyan'}));
});
```

So, no need to pipe *.coffee files through gulp-mocha

Comment: I'm aware of how to use coffeescript (and frankly agree that a lot of time gulp/grunt are overused on node), but this isn't an answer to the question. In fact, its only instructions on how to install a coffee-script package locally. This will not actually run mocha specs.

Comment: You most likely misunderstood what I meant by installing coffeescript. Please read my updated answer.